# Query different collections across multiple MongoDB servers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two MongoDB database instances, Database A and Database B. Database A contains Collection X. Database B contains Collection Y. They share an index and can be assumed to have a one-to-one relationship.

The reason for this setup is strictly a business decision and cannot be changed.

To respond to an API, they eventually need to be merged into a single array that holds new objects containing information from both Collection X and Collection Y. The API allows filtering against data elements in each collection. How can I query against both collections?

The best "solution" I've come up with so far is to fetch the collections from both databases and then, in memory, merge them using something like the below Javascript (utilizing the Lodash library):

```js
_.map(collectionX, (item) => 
    _.extend(item, {
        _metadata: _.find(collectionY, {sharedId: item.sharedId})
    })
);
```

Is there a better, more efficient manner to do this kind of query?

Comment: There is a good reason business shouldn't dictate technical implementation. Your pseudo-code doesn't really explain what you are doing, but if you do query mongo in a loop stop doing it. Make 2 queries one to dbA.CollectionX, another  to dbB.CollectionY, then merge results in memory.

Comment: @AlexBlex The Javascript is doing essentially what you just suggested: taking two already queried collections and merging them. I'm just wondering if there's anything better than that.

Comment: Only minor optimisation on js side. Convert collectionY to object, and use `_metadata: collectionY[item.sharedId]` instead of `find()`